# Integrate OpenStreetMap in Android?

Tags: openstreetmap, android, offline

I'm newbie to Android Offline Map Integration, I have a problem in offline map integration, I take a month to analysis the offline map integration.  Here I referred to **Osmdroid** **Osmand** and few other programs, I have an idea about map data in vector format, but till now I don't have initial level progress.

Please can you to give some reference code for Map Integration using vector format and POI data Integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [mapsforge](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge) ... this framework uses offline vector map files based on OpenStreetMap.

next to the source code on github, there is also a quite active mailing list on googlegroups.

On github you can find some wiki articles how to start, and also a sample app with all basic feeatures.

Comment: Thank you very much stephan. do you have any links regarding  the offline map integration in android. kindly share the links you'e.

Comment: His answer already contains a link. Also take a look at the [Android page in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).